# Can't compile 64 bit CXTipListBox

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, listbox

I am trying to take the `CXTipListBox` from the classes here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4438/XTipComboBox-Display-tooltips-for-combobox

To use it for a `CListBox` control on a dialog.

It compiles and runs fine in MFC Win32 32 bit.

But 64 bit will not compile and says:

```
7>XTipListBox.cpp
7>D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\XTipListBox.cpp(38,2): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl CXTipListBox::* )(UINT)' to 'void (__cdecl CWnd::* )(UINT_PTR)'
7>D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\XTipListBox.cpp(38,2): message : Cast from base to derived requires dynamic_cast or static_cast
```

[image]

I am stumped.

Comment: You probably just need to change the `CXTipListBox`'s `OnTimer()` signature from taking a `UINT` to accepting a `UINT_PTR` instead. Make sure to check its implementation, too, to see if it makes assumptions about the argument's size and adjust those as needed.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you. I’ll investigate that. I did look at the signiature for differences but only looked at the return value and forgot about the parameters.

Comment: @IInspectable All is now good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft started shipping 64-bit versions of Windows XP for mainstream CPU architectures in 2005. The library in question (XTipComboBox) was published in 2003, understandably, without 64-bit support. The compiler error is a testament to that:

> ```
> cannot convert from 'void (CXTipListBox::* )(UINT)' to 'void (CWnd::* )(UINT_PTR)'
> ```

This starts in the [`ON_WM_TIMER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/wm-messages-t-z) macro. Like all message map entry macros, it requires a particular signature for the callback (and, in this case, also a fixed name, `OnTimer`). The mismatch between the class types in the member function pointer types [is allowed](https://godbolt.org/z/PK587MEhe); it's the argument's type causing the build to fail.

`UINT` is a type alias for `unsigned int` (a 32-bit unsigned integer) for all architectures. The `UINT_PTR` type introduced in the migration to 64-bit Windows is still a type alias for `unsigned int` for 32-bit builds but aliases `unsigned __int64` for 64-bit architectures. This is why a 32-bit build succeeds while a 64-bit build fails.

To resolve this issue, the library code needs to be updated by changing the `OnTimer` class member's parameter list from taking a `UINT` to accepting a `UINT_PTR` instead<sup>1</sup>. It may be required to update the *implementation* correspondingly to account for the potentially wider type. The [Programming Guide for 64-bit Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/programming-guide-for-64-bit-windows) is a valuable resource to find further information on this.

---

Timer IDs (and IDs in general) are frequently the source of confusion. The requirement for an ID to be unique rarely raises an eyebrow. Things turn fuzzy from here unless you follow up with two more questions:

- What's the available repertoire (space)?
- How long does the ID need to be unique (time)?

A timer ID needs to be unique for the lifetime of a thread and can take on the value of any address. The latter is often overlooked as an opportunity. [A window can't have two timers with the same ID, so how do I assign an ID that nobody else is using?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191009-00/?p=102974) takes a comprehensive look at this property and offers actionable insights.

---

<sup>1</sup> *This has no adverse effect for 32-bit builds. `UINT` and `UINT_PTR` alias the **same** type for 32-bit architectures, so this change is inconsequential.*